# Cross Disolve working on iPhone but not iPad

Tags: iphone, core-animation, ipad

I have the following code that gets called after the view loads.  It works perfectly on the iPhone, but appears to do nothing at all on the iPad.  I have confirmed the frame/bounds of my UIImageView is set to the size of the iPad's screen. Recommendations please?

```
- (void)startNextAnimation {
 CABasicAnimation *crossFade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
 crossFade.fromValue = imageFrom;
 //crossFade.fromValue = (id)(imageFrom.CGImage);
 crossFade.toValue = imageTo;
 //crossFade.toValue = (id)(imageTo.CGImage);
 crossFade.delegate = self;
 crossFade.duration = 5.0f;
 crossFade.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
 crossFade.removedOnCompletion = NO;
 [bgPattern.layer addAnimation:crossFade forKey:@"animateContents"];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, nothing to see here.  This had to do with iOS 4 not requiring the image extension, and 3.2 still needing it.  All solved.